# Clojure: Cannot launch cider repl with boot

Tags: clojure, boot, cider

I have the following build.boot file,

```
(set-env!
 :resource-paths #{"src"}
 :dependencies '[[me.raynes/conch "0.8.0"]
                 [boot.core :as boot]])
(task-options!
 pom {:project 'myapp
      :version "0.1.0"}
 jar {:manifest {"Foo" "bar"}})
(boot/deftask cider "CIDER profile"
  []
  (require 'boot.repl)
  (swap! @(resolve 'boot.repl/default-dependencies)
         concat '[[org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12"]
                  [cider/cider-nrepl "0.15.0"]
                  [refactor-nrepl "2.3.1"]])
  (swap! @(resolve 'boot.repl/default-middleware)
         concat '[cider.nrepl/cider-middleware
                  refactor-nrepl.middleware/wrap-refactor])
  identity)
```

following this documentation: https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Cider-REPL
However, upon doing cider-jack-in I get the error "refusing to run as root. set BOOT_AS_ROOT=yes to force.", and yet after doing export BOOT_AS_ROOT=yes, I get the same error. What's wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to run Boot as your `root` user or are you getting this error when using a regular user?

Comment: My spacemacs is running in sudo, so yeah.

Comment: boot is likely running as the root user.

Answer (score 0):

This wiki page is super outdated, so I don't recommend following it. I'd be best to read [CIDER's documentation](https://docs.cider.mx/cider/basics/up_and_running.html) instead.

Just make sure you're using Boot 2.8.3. You don't really need any special CIDER profile. Just create a Boot project, open a file from it in CIDER and do `M-x cider-jack-in-clj`.

Comment: Well thanks. But that of course doesn't help with the core of the issue that BOOT_AS_ROOT isn't defined for cider.

Comment: Why would that be?

Comment: You can set environment variables from Emacs as described here https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Environment.html Still, probably it'd be easier to just run `boot repl` outside of Emacs and use `cider-connect` to connect to the running REPL server.